Code Composer Studio tconf can't create session manager: specified script is not a file
I need to run tconf from DSP/BIOS 5_42_02_10 from the command line. When I do this from a cmd DOS, it works:
C:\ti\bios_5_42_02_10\xdctools\tconf.exe -b -Dconfig.importPath="C:/ti/bios_5_42_02_10/packages" .\my_project.tcf

When I repeat the same command in Powershell, I get:
C:\ti\bios_5_42_02_10\xdctools\tconf.exe: can't create session manager: specified script is not a file


Does it work if you supply the full path to the tcf file?

@MathiasR.Jessen no, it doesn't
